# Simple If statement not working

Tags: if-statement, count

My assignment is to count how many occurrences a certain number appears in a sorted array. 
My code:

```
public static void count_occurences(Integer[] v, Integer k) {
           int count = 0;
            int start = 0; 
            System.out.println();
            for(int i = 826; i < v.length; i++){
                System.out.println(v[i]);
                System.out.println(k);
                if(v[i] == (Integer)k){
                    count++;
                }
        }
            System.out.print(count);
        }
```

doesn't seem to be working when the array is as large as the one I'm using as it traverses right past the integer "828" which I'm looking for. Is there some sort of bug with if statements that happens when data is too large or something? I'm very confused.

Comment: The bug is not wtih IF statement , The bug is the way you use it

Comment: How many elements are there in your array?  You are ignoring the first 826 of them.  Please show example output from your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

integers are classes, you have to use the equals method otherwise you're comparing if they're the same object. You want to check if they represent the same thing

```
v[i].equals((Integer)k)
```

Also, you start at i at 826, you need to start at 0.